# Indenting in a txt file from python script in terminal

Tags: python

Im trying to write a python script that will make a txt file if there isn't a current one and add "Indent Me Somewhere Onto The Next Line" this text to it. I am wondering how the text could be indented in the middle of the string onto the next line with the least amount of python. Thanks everyone.

```
    import sys
    if not os.path.exists(/Users/you/Desktop/AIMemory.txt) :
        memory = open("AIMemory.txt","w")
        print("Created A New Memory")
    else :
        print("Accessing Memory")
        memory = open("AIMemory.txt", "r")
        print(memory.read())
        memory.close()
    memory = open("AIMemory.txt", "a")
    memory.write("Indent Me Somewhere Onto The Next Line")
```

Comment: try to put "\t" before  "Ident Me ..."

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me, while it indents the text it does not push it onto a new line

Comment: At the end put "\n"

Comment: Wonderful thank you so much. I don't know why I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a tab character and linefeed at the end, like:

```
memory.write("\tIndent Me Somewhere Onto The Next Line\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put 
`memory.write("\tIndent me onto the next line \n")`.

OR

`memory.write("\n\tIndent me onto the next line ")`, if you want the first line to be blank.